# React-native flatlist renderItem

Tags: react-native

I have a array dictionary. I want to render all value to flatlist. 
I try:

> renderItem = {({item}) => item.A.id}

But I don't return any value. Please help me. thanks

```
ArrAccount: {
  "A": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Anh Tuan Nguyen",
      "age": 28
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "An Nhien",
      "age": 2
    },
  ],
  "Z": [
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Thanh Tu Pham",
      "age": 32
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Tien Thanh",
      "age": 24
    },
  ]
}
```

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `this.props.myArrayAccount` field like this

```
this.props.myArrayAccount = {
        ArrAccount: {
          "A": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Anh Tuan Nguyen",
              "age": 28
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "An Nhien",
              "age": 2
            },
          ],
          "Z": [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "name": "Thanh Tu Pham",
              "age": 32
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "name": "Tien Thanh",
              "age": 24
            },
          ]
        }
      }

const myArrayAccount = this.props.myArrayAccount.ArrAccount
const ArrAccount = Object.keys(myArrayAccount).map((key)=> myArrayAccount[key])
```

because your `props` has more than one object inside it you should should `map` the object first than map the `Flatlist` component

you your data in `FlatList` component should like this:

```
{ArrAccount.map((item) =>
    <FlatList
      data={item}
      renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.name}</Text>}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to get all value of array( A and Z or many). Do you have any way to help me?

Comment: i already update my answer to get value of your object just tell me if this fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `renderItem` like this:

```
renderItem = {({item:data}) => <Text>data.id</Text>}
```

And this will list all the ids.

Note: this style is so simple you can customize the style of items.

Comment: I try but no return value.
<FlatList
   data = {this.props.myArrayAccount}
   renderItem = {({item:data}) => <Text>{data.id}</Text>}
 />